# What's going on here with scala.collection.immutable.Stack.+: (prepend)?

Tags: scala

I noticed that the ScalaDoc for immutable Stack refers to a method prepend with the following signature:

```
class Stack[A+] ...
  def +: (elem: A): Stack[A]
```

That method signature looked wrong to me because Stack is covariant in the A type parameter (so the type of elem should be a compiler error). What's more, Scaladoc says that the definition of this method is in GenSeqLike but it doesn't appear to be there.

SeqLike has an implementation of +: that I imagine is the one that's being used by Stack.

```
trait SeqLike[+A, +Repr] ...
  def +:[B >: A, That](elem: B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
    val b = bf(repr)
    b += elem
    b ++= thisCollection
    b.result
  }
```

This doesn't look to be as efficient as Stack.push.

When I try to provide my own implementation of +: (as push), I do get the expected compiler errors that the method I'm overriding doesn't exist and about the covariance issue.

```
class Stack2[+A] extends Stack[A] {
  override def +: (elem: A): Stack[A] = this push elem
}
```

scalac Stack2.scala gives:

```
Stack2.scala:4: error: method +: overrides nothing
  override def +: (elem: A): Stack[A] = this push elem
               ^
Stack2.scala:4: error: covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of value elem
  override def +: (elem: A): Stack[A] = this push elem
                   ^
two errors found
```

Is it possible to implement +: efficiently using push?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation is a little confusing here.  You'll notice that that method is marked as a *use case*.  The actual signature is this one:

```
def +: [B >: A, That] (elem: B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Stack[A], B, That]): That
Prepends an element to this immutable stack
```

The use case is just showing a typical way you might use it (and even though the real signature changed in `SeqLike`, the use case didn't change from `GenSeqLike`, hence the apparently incorrect attribution).

You're correct that the implementation of `+:` is not efficient, though you couldn't tell this for certain given the code that you posted.  `b ++= thisCollection` *could* notice that the rest of it is just a stack and push `elem` on the front.  But it doesn't; `b` is just an `ArrayBuffer` underneath the hood.

So use a list instead, like the doc suggests.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the [use case] thing.

Comment: Just for kicks, I'm still trying to override prepend on the more general (actual) method definition with the CanBuildFrom. I can't see how I can use Stack.push to implement it. The CanBuildFrom seems to force the use of a mutable collection like ArrayBuffer. https://github.com/steshaw/playground/commit/5f5abb9693d19663d2945815290589d8529b31fc

Comment: @Steven Shaw - It's not at all straightforward, I agree.